# Can the E Adhaar card or the Nationalized Bank Passbook be used as identify proof?

Tags: india, jet-airways

Can the E Adhaar card or the Nationalized Bank Passbook be used as identify proof for traveling with Jet Airways within India?

Comment: While the questions are not identical, the response provides id requirements and links for Jet Airways and Air India.